# How to read a traceback in R

Tags: r, function, loops, traceback

I have a large dataset of polygons and, with a loop, I am trying at some point to find, calculate and store intersections. On the 870th iteration, the loop stops and I get the error :

```
Error in RGEOSBinTopoFunc(spgeom1, spgeom2, byid, id, drop_lower_td, unaryUnion_if_byid_false,  : 
  TopologyException: Input geom 0 is invalid: Ring Self-intersection at or near point 26.437120350000001 39.241770119999998 at 26.437120350000001 39.241770119999998
```

I use `traceback()` but I can not actually understand it:

```
4: .Call("rgeos_intersection", .RGEOS_HANDLE, spgeom1, spgeom2, 
       byid, ids, PACKAGE = "rgeos")
3: RGEOSBinTopoFunc(spgeom1, spgeom2, byid, id, drop_lower_td, unaryUnion_if_byid_false, 
       "rgeos_intersection")
2: gIntersection(combinations[[i]][[1, m]], combinations[[i]][[2, 
       m]]) at #17 . Can anyone explain what to look in ` traceback`?
```

Can anyone explain me what to look in `traceback`?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It literally shows you the way the functions were called and where the error occurred. Check this example:

```
a <- function(x) {
  b <- function(y) {
    c <- function(z) {
     stop('there was a problem')  
    }
    c()
  }
  b()
}
```

When I call `a()`:

```
> a()

Error in c() : there was a problem 
4. stop("there was a problem") 
3. c() 
2. b() 
1. a()
```

In the above example you can see that `a` called `b` which called `c` and then in `c` the error occurred. It shows you the calling environments.

Comment: So, please correct me if I am wrong, it starts with the general function in 1. and then on the last call/number (in that case 4.) it shows me the error? It does not actually means that the entire function is wrong.

Comment: Yes exactly. It starts with 1 and reaches 4 where it breaks. It is hard to say which of your functions is wrong though. Maybe you have a logical error at 1, which causes the function at 4 to fail. Syntactically though your function works well until it breaks.

Comment: Thank you very much, now I understand the way it works and I will try to solve my problem. Thanks!